# Select on CLOB XML DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have this data as `CLOB` field in DB2. I am converting the data to `char` using cast:

```
SELECT CAST(CLOBColumn as VARCHAR(32000))
FROM Schema.MyTable;
```

Here is how the result XML comes out from the above:

```
<TreeList TreeNo="ABC">
    <Tree ErrorCode="INVALID_TREE" ErrorDescription="Tree doesn’t exist." TreeID="123456"/>
    <Tree ErrorCode="INVALID_TREE" ErrorDescription="Tree doesn’t exist." TreeID="1234567"/>
</TreeList>
```

And this is how I expect my output

```
|TreeNo | TreeID  |   ErrorCode  | ErrorDescription
|ABC    | 123456  | INVALID_TREE | Tree doesn’t exist
|ABC    | 1234567 | INVALID_TREE | Tree doesn’t exist
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What is the question...?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [XMLTABLE function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0023903.html) which allows to map XML data to a table. You can pass in XML-typed data and it works if you directly parse the CLOB to XML. The SELECT would look like the following (you get the idea):

```
SELECT x.*
FROM schema.mytable, XMLTABLE(
    '$CLOBColumn/TreeList'
    COLUMNS 
    TreeNo VARCHAR(10) PATH '@TreeNo',
    TreeID INT PATH 'Tree[@TreeID]',
    ...
) AS x
;
```